# change python interpreter for scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a Scrapy project running on a Windows machine and using PyCharm as the IDE, with everything working fine.

I uploaded this project on another device running on Raspbian. On every page of this script, when I try to import `scrapy` or one of its modules, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named scrapy
```

Things that I've tried but didn't get any result:

1. Remove `scrapy` and install it again with and without `sudo`
2. Recreate the project structure with `scrapy startproject project_name` and replace the content into files

And I'm still getting the same error for not recognizing `scrapy`.

This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from exchange.spiders.oxe import OxeSpider
process.crawl(OxeSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: Did you actually install scrapy on the device you're trying to run the code on?

Comment: @stranac What? You mean i'm joking and i'm wasting my time and yours? I did install it and it runs well when i type `scrapy` in command line.

Comment: Just trying to debug the problem. People sometimes make silly mistakes, and it wasn't obvious to me from your description (although I guess there's no sudo on windows). So `scrapy` on its own works, but `scrapy crawl yourspider` results in an `ImportError`?

Comment: @stranac I have a file that call the spiders in it. the spiders themselves are working without this error. The file that contains spiders and runs with error, is in the root directory of project where the `scrapy.cfg` file is.

Comment: Can you share the file that calls the spiders? How exactly it does it is probably important.

Comment: @stranac Added the code.

Comment: Are there multiple python versions installed on the device? If so, make sure that the correct python version is used to run this script.

Comment: @stranac Yes i'm Running python 2.7 and 3.5 on my server. How i define the python version for the project ?

Comment: If you're running it using pycharm, take a look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm-edu/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html If you're running it from the terminal, just run the correct version directly, e.g. `python3 myscript.py`

Comment: It's a good idea to use virtualenv for your projects. It allows you to create virtual environments with specified python versions and its own lists of installed packages.